# size() of std::array pointer in constexpr context

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang++, constant-expression

Let's say I have a function like:

```
int test(std::array<char, 8>* data) {
  char buffer[data->size() * 2];

  [... some code ...]
}
```

clearly the size of the buffer can be evaluated at compile time: data has a `constexpr` size of 8 elements, 8 * 2 = 16 bytes.

However, when compiling with `-Wall`, `-pedantic` and `-std=c++11` I get the infamous error:

> warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]

which I believe makes sense: `array::size()` is `constexpr`, but it is still a method, and in the function above we still have to dereference a pointer, which is not `constexpr`.

If I try something like:

```
int test(std::array<char, 8>& data) {
  char buffer[data.size() * 2];
  [...]
}
```

`gcc` (tried version 5.2.0) seems happy: there is no warning.

But with `clang++` (3.5.1) I still get a warning complaining about variable length arrays.

In my case, I can't easily change the signature of `test`, it has to take a pointer. So... a few questions:

1. What is the best / most standard way to get the size of a `std::array` **pointer** in constexpr context?
2. Is the difference in behavior with pointers vs references expected? Which compiler is right about the warning, `gcc` or `clang`?

Comment: It'd be interesting to know why `size` isn't a static member function..

Comment: I should also add that there's probably some way to get the size via a template, something like:

    `template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    std::size_t arraysize(const std::array<T, N>& array) { return N; }`

which could be used above. Still... is this the right way? Seems contorted.

Comment: I could see it failing in the pointer case but not the reference case since technically, the pointer might be `nullptr`; sure, it can't do anything useful there, but it also means the `size` isn't properly defined. If `size` were virtual, I could see it complaining with both pointers and references (because it might be a type derived from `std::array<char, 8>` that doesn't have the same `size` implementation), but that's clearly not the case here.

Comment: Maybe clang complain because reference are implemented through const pointer ? So even with a reference in depth the compiler still have to dereference it ?

Comment: @Pumkko: Your answer was getting some negative comments from inattentive people, but it absolutely did answer "What is the best / most standard way to get the size of a `std::array`?"  You could have fixed the "too generic" complaint by specifying `char` and only inferring the size.

Comment: Would it be possible to do something like `std::tuple_size<decltype(*arr)>::value` ?

Comment: It seems the issue is that the compilers see `&*data` in the case of the pointer or `&data` in the case of the reference, and an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of it, and report an error because this address cannot be a constant expression. The address is used to initialize the `this` pointer, implicitly via [expr.call]p4.

Comment: @DragonRock You'd need to add a `remove_reference_t`, which makes it quite long.

Comment: Technically it's a warning, not an error, thing you'd get if you strictly required a constant expression as in `constexpr auto s = data.size()`, since it is not a constant expression afaics.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know about 2.

But for 1, we can do this:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr std::integral_constant<size_t, N> array_size( std::array<T, N> const& ) {
  return {};
}
```

then:

```
void test(std::array<char, 8>* data) {
  using size=decltype(array_size(*data));
  char buffer[size{}];
  (void)buffer;
  // [... some code ...]
}
```

alternatively:

```
template<class T, class U, size_t N>
std::array<T,N> same_sized_array( std::array< U, N > const& ) {
  return {};
}

void test(std::array<char, 8>* data) {
  auto buffer = same_sized_array<char>(*data);
  (void)buffer;
  // [... some code ...]
}
```

finally, a C++14 cleanup:

```
template<class A>
constexpr const decltype(array_size( std::declval<A>() )) array_size_v = {};

void test3(std::array<char, 8>* data) {
  char buffer[array_size_v<decltype(*data)>];
  (void)buffer;
  // [... some code ...]
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8398719f7d5b5a94).

Comment: @dyp I could add volatile if you want? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The good old C way would be a define, but C++ has `const int` or for C++11 `constexpr`. So if you want the compiler to be aware that the size of the array is a compile time constant, the most portable(*) way would be to make it a `const` or `constexpr`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

const size_t sz = 8;  // constexpr size_t sz for c++11

int test(std::array<char, sz>* data) {
  char buffer[sz * 2];

  buffer[0] = 0;
  return 0;
}
int main()
{
    std::array<char, sz> arr = { { 48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55 } };
    int cr = test(&arr);
    std::cout << cr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without a warning, even with `-Wall -pedantic` under Clang 3.4.1

For the second question, I cannot imagine why gcc make that difference between pointers and refs here. Either it can determine that `size()` method on an `std::array` whose size is a constant is a constant expression - and it should allow both - or it cannot - and it should emit same warning on both. But it does not only concern the compiler, but also the standard library implementation.

The real problem is that pre-C++11 std::array was not part of the standard library, and `constexpr` is also defined only from C++11 on. So in pre-C++11 mode, both compiler process std::array as an extension, but there is no way for the `size` method to declare its return value to be a constant expr. This explains why Clang (and gcc facing a pointer) emits the warning.

But if you compile original code in c++11 mode (`-std=c++11`) you should have no warning, because the standard requires `size()` method on a `std::array` to be a `constexpr`.

(*) The question is about *best / most standard* ; I cannot say what is *best* way, and I cannot define *most standard* either, so I stick to what I would use if I wanted to avoid portability problems on non C++11 compilers.

Comment: *"But if you compile original code in c++11 mode (`-std=c++11`) you should have no warning, because the standard requires `size()` method on a std::array to be a `constexpr`."* A `constexpr` (member) function does not need to produce a constant expression when called.

Comment: @dyp: For me, and for [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) *[t]he `constexpr` specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time*. So a `constexpr` function with no parameters *is* required do produce something that can be used wherever a litteral constant could be. If it takes parameters, it is required to do so only if its parameters are constant expressions themselves.

Comment: Here's an example: `struct foo { int i; constexpr int bar() { return i; } }; int main() { foo f{rand()}; constexpr auto x = f.bar(); }`

Comment: @dyp: when compiling with -std=c++11, clang says : *error: constexpr variable 'x' must be initialized by a constant
      expression
    constexpr auto x = f.bar();*. The `constexpr` specifier on `bar` method says that the result will be a constant expression provided  the object has been initialized with a constant expression. In `std::array` the size shall be a constant expression so the method `constexpr size_type size() const noexcept;` **is required** to return a constant expression, and a conformant C++11 compiler should **not** issue any warning.

Comment: @dyp: Followup to my first comment: A `constexpr` method is required to return a constant expression if the object was initialized with constant expressions only (or nothing) and if its parameters are constant expressions themselves (or are empty).

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding proof for that in the Standard. However, I agree with the notion: I don't quite understand why the OP is not a constant expression. I can only guess it has to do with the `this` parameter, as I've mentioned in a comment to the OP.

Comment: Also, consider `constexpr int bar() { return i > 42 ? i : throw i; }` as a member function. It does not produce a constant expression if the object (instance) has been initialized with a constant expression but the value of `i` is smaller or equal to 42.

Comment: @dyp: your example in not far from the first in *7.1.5 The constexpr specifier [dcl.constexpr] §5* : `constexpr int f(bool b)
{ return b ? throw 0 : 0; } // OK
constexpr int f() { return f(true); } // ill-formed, no diagnostic required` (assuming you meant `constexpr int bar(int i) ...`). Using `bar(21)` as a constant expression would result in an ill-formed program. And as standard says explicitely that no diagnostic would be required we just invoke undefined behaviour :-(

Comment: No, I mean `struct foo { int i; constexpr int bar() { return i > 42 ? i : throw i; } };`. Then, `constexpr foo f0{43}; constexpr auto x = f0.bar();` is well-formed, but `constexpr auto f1{41}; constexpr auto y = f1.bar();` is ill-formed.

Comment: fwiw, I was using `-std=c++11` in all the experiments I run. I just added that in the original question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `std::tuple_size` on the decltype of your parameter ?

```
void test(std::array<char, 8>* data) {
    using data_type = std::remove_pointer<decltype(data)>::type;
    char buffer[std::tuple_size<data_type>::value * 2];
    static_assert(sizeof buffer == 16, "Ouch");
    // [... some code ...]
}
```